# Cognos SDK DataSourceConnection Powercube

Tags: java, cognos, cognos-bi

I am currently working with the Cognos SDK and I want to add a DataSourceConnection to a DataSource that is in "IBM Cognos PowerCube" - Query Mode / Type. I managed to add a DataSourceConnection to a DataSource but the Query Mode appeared to be in "other type". I need the type / query mode: "IBM Cognos PowerCube" for my DataSourceConnection. Who can I set that Query Mode for my DataSourceConnection in the SDK?

Thank for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:
You have to write in the StringProps something like this:
`;default;PC;WINDIR=;UNIXDIR;`

If you hand the stringprop to your datasource connection it will be a IBM Cognos Powercube